# Can $where be used inside $match?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I am using the following query:

```
{ $match: { $where: "price > 5" }}
```

But it is throwing error as:
`exception: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'." , "code" : 16410 , "ok" : 0.0}`

Comment: Are you using aggregation? There's a note at the bottom of this page ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/ ) that reads `Warning You cannot use $where in $match queries as part of the aggregation pipeline.`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I rememeber, it's something like

```
{$match: {"price":{$gt:5}}
```